window.opener and window.parent not working in popup child window
I am building a microsoft teams tab and I'd like to be able to authenticate with an existing sso flow. However, the way teams work is that it embeds your app in an iframe. So I have an iframe of domain-x with a button that opens up domain-y and has some redirects as part of the auth process. Let's say the team's client is at domain-z.
So;
domain-x is an iframe in domain-z. There is a button in domain-x that opens domain-y. I want to be able to communicate back to domain-x iframe but it seems like window.parent = window.self and window.opener = null when I open the popup so I can't use parent.postMessage with an event listener. There is some cross-site security at play here which is really tricky.
in domain-x
<button onclick="window.open('domain-y', 'popup=true')">

in domain-y
<script>
    parent.postMessage("done", "*")
</script>

in domain-z
<iframe :src="domain-x"></iframe>

Is there any way I can get domain-y to post a message back to domain-x?
If this is simply not possible, maybe I save the result of the authentication in a database and poll it from the parent iframe and if I find a result I redirect?
Has anyone done this before? Any advice would be helpful.

As a long shot, could you create an offscreen iframe on domain z and then have that open the child window? That way the extra iframe could relay messages.

Or have the child window open on one of the other domains with an iframe set to 100vh/100vw? And relay through that?

I'm not 100% I understand. I think I get the idea but wouldn't the cross-origin issues still occur? @DavidBradshaw

The SSO story has changed a HUGE amount over the years with Teams and improved dramatically, so you (a) aren't ABLE to launch own popup but (b) don't NEED to launch one. Please follow the latest docs and you should come right: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview

I interpret this as building an internal app. I want to build an app that is published to the teams store for others to download and sso into. Really, I just need to verify this person has logged into their email as I am generating a magic login link for them to redirect to. I don’t have the ability to set up anything with the organizations downloading this app so I’m not sure if the tab sso docs is what I’m trying to do.

This SSO mechanism is meant for both scenarios. I have an app in the store also, using it. You only need to create the Azure AD app in your own tenant - the other tenants will have it auto-created for them when someone 'consents' to use your app (they click OK on the 'consent' popup, you might have seen it with other apps or various types in M365).

I’d love to know more about this. A pop up opens and asks them to login to Microsoft, they login with their outlook/live email and get an auth token that is passed back which verifies their identity. This is locked into an outlook email, right?  If they have created an account with my app with gmail but have an outlook email for teams, this wouldn’t work?

Is this also the same way we get access to the graph api?

Yes, it's the same way to get a Graph token - you can search for OBO, or "On Behalf Of" token. I'm not following your previous comment though. If they're using your app inside Teams, then you don't need to worry about the 'type' of account - they have a Teams account already, by definition. How did they sign in via Gmail in that case?

My app is an existing web app that I’m embedding into the teams client so many users already have an account. Some of them with gmail. It may end up going down the path of a single identity for a user that may have 2 emails. But only one is used as the source of truth for the account login. But OBO is great, I’d like to be able to access a user’s calendar so I’d need access to the graph api token regardless.

I’ve actually decided to just use the Microsoft SSO route. I am overengineering and will leverage this. Thank you!

ok sounds good. You'll need the additional info on the user account, but I think overall this is a more simple, correct path. Incidentally, you don't need to store the team email per se, rather the user's AD/Entra Id property (guid).

So essentially I am requesting an auth token and Microsoft prompts for a user to login. If they login, an auth token is returned and that tells me they are authenticated. But is there an extra step I can take to validate the token is for the user?

yes, absolutely you should be validating the token on your backend - see more here, albeit quite detailed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/access-tokens#validating-tokens . In simple terms, you want to send the token to your backend as a Bearer token in the Auth header, and then do JWT validation - it should match your Azure AD ("Entra ID") App details, and will also contain the user's AadObjectId and Tenant ID

So users may already have an account in my app. I use login links to log users in.
So as long as the token is validated, we say this user is authenticated. I can pull their email (required for login) and trust that and just log them in? The other objects don’t really mean anything to my app aside from validating the token MS sends me. I’m just trying to grasp this a bit better as the security is a bit blurry and I’m not 100% certain how I can just trust this auth token and log a user into my app.

I'm guessing you're using Google Sign In for you app to sign Google Account users in? If so, you should consider offering Microsoft account sign in as well, especially considering you're wanting to integrate with the Microsoft ecosystem. Once that's done, you could conceptually allow the user to sign in with -either- (i.e. -both- options) by storing their unique user id from each of those systems in your database. With that done, you can then handle the user logging in with either system, e.g. Google in the browser or Microsoft in browser or Teams.

For the Google route, I think you need to do a validation on the backend to ensure the token is valid. For Microsoft it's basically the same, and therefore you can do the validation for their sign in via Teams in basically the same way.

I’m actually using a magic login link so it doesn’t matter the domain. I was just wondering if after requesting an auth token and validating that token, if I could generate a link to redirect them to it if their email exists in my DB? Microsoft calls their token an auth token and an identity token so is it safe to do this?
